# Put div under another div with responsive design

Tags: html, css, web

The HEADER div is the content of the website. Its width is 80% of the actual screen size, and it's positioned at the center of the screen too.

This is the HTML Code. What I want is the "one" div to be above the "two" div when the screen size is smaller. When you open the website on the computer, the two divs must be next to each other, but for example when the window is 320px then the two divs must be  one on top of the other (just like the classic responsive designs)

This is the code:

```css
#header {
width: 88%;
margin: 0 auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 80px -10px #0B0B3B;
-moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 80px -10px #0B0B3B;
box-shadow: -2px 2px 80px -10px #000;
}

.wrapper { 
  border : 2px solid #000; 
  overflow:hidden;
}

.wrapper div {
   min-height: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
}
#one {
  background-color: gray;
  float:left; 
  margin-right:20px;
  width:140px;
  border-right:2px solid #000;
}
#two { 
  background-color: white;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:10px;
  border:2px dashed #ccc;
  min-height:170px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    body {
        background-image: url("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/max-width479.png");
    }

    #one { 
    float: none;
    margin-right:0;
    width:auto;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;    
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header"> 
    <div class="wrapper">
       <div id="one">one</div>
       <div id="two">two</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of the concept:
https://codepen.io/mikeabeln_nwea/pen/ZRgKwv

The problem is partially caused by the `float` that you're using. `float` almost always causes problems as it removes the element from the DOM order, which you don't want in this case.

What you want to do is use `display: inline-block` when you want the two `div` tags to be next to each other, and then media query that statement to `display: block` when you want the two `div` tags to be stacked.

The other problem you're having is putting the text directly in the `div` tags. You want to use those as containers for text elements, such as the `p` tag used in my example.

CSS file:

```
.header {
   width: 88%;
   margin: auto;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 80px -10px #0B0B3B;
   -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 80px -10px #0B0B3B;
   box-shadow: -2px 2px 80px -10px #000;
}

.wrapper{
   width: 100%;
}

.box{
   vertical-align: top;
   display: inline-block;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 170px;
}

.one {
   background-color: gray;
   width: 20%;
}

.two { 
   background-color: white;
   width: 79%;
   border:2px dashed #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .box{
      display: block;
   }

   .one {
      width: 100%;
   }

   .two {
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```

HTML file:

```
<div class="header"> 
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="box one">
       <p>one</p>
     </div>
     <div class="box two">
       <p>two</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use syntax

```
@media only screen and (max-width:320px){/your css here}
```

hope it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `display:block;` and `width:100%` instead of auto

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    #one {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    //other stuff..
    }
}
```